How to send transaction from wallet with secret key
I am trying to send a transaction from a wallet using secret key. I am trying to execute it using @solana/web3.js. Here's the script that I have created but it is not working for some reason.
"use server";

import { TokenVault } from "@/anchor/types/token_vault";
import token_vault_idl from "@/anchor/idl/token_vault.json";
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program, BN, AnchorProvider, Idl } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import * as web3 from "@solana/web3.js";
import NodeWallet from "@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/nodewallet";

export async function destake(tokenAccount: string) {
  const payer = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(
    //secret key here
  );
  const wallet = new NodeWallet(payer);

  const url = web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet");

  let connection = new web3.Connection(url, "confirmed");

  const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {
    commitment: "processed",
  });

  //Create Program Instance
  const programId = new web3.PublicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROGRAM_ID);
  const program = new Program(
    token_vault_idl as Idl,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROGRAM_ID,
    provider
  );

  const DUMMY_TOKEN_ADDRESS = new web3.PublicKey(
    "Gh9ZwEmdLJ8DscKNTkTqPbNwLNNBjuSzaG9Vp2KGtKJr"
  );

  //Create required PDAs
  const [tokenAccountOwnerPda] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("token_account_owner_pda")],
    programId
  );
  const [tokenVault] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("token_vault"), DUMMY_TOKEN_ADDRESS.toBuffer()],
    programId
  );
  const [stakeInfo] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("stake_info"), new web3.PublicKey(tokenAccount).toBuffer()],
    program.programId
  );

  console.log("Stake Info", stakeInfo.toString());

  const destakeInstruction = await program.methods
    .destake(new BN(5 * 10 ** 6), payer.publicKey)
    .accounts({
      tokenAccountOwnerPda,
      vaultTokenAccount: tokenVault,
      stakeInfo: stakeInfo,
      mintOfTokenBeingSent: DUMMY_TOKEN_ADDRESS,
      senderTokenAccount: new web3.PublicKey(tokenAccount),
    })
    .signers([payer])
    .transaction();

  console.log(destakeInstruction);

  const txHash = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    destakeInstruction,
    [payer]
  );

  console.log("Transaction Hash", txHash);

  const { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } =
    await program.provider.connection.getLatestBlockhash();

  await program.provider.connection.confirmTransaction({
    blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight,
    signature: txHash,
  });

  console.log(
    `Solana Explorer: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txHash}?cluster=devnet`
  );
}



please share the error logs too

I am facing errors like undefined blockhash and feepayer.
